How do I update a masterlist with already existing data with new monthly data in Excel?
For the sake of simplicity, I only provide a simple masterlist with not more than 10 rows.
So here's a masterlist:

The masterlist has all assets waiting to be updated monthly. The list only has data from June. Now here's the list for July:

I want to update the masterlist with the data from July with two conditions: 1. It doesn't affect data from previous months (In this case, only June) 2. Only specific columns marked by red boxes will be updated. As for now, I use VLOOKUP to update the masterlist but it's time consuming because in real life I'm dealing with thousands of data. Moreover, I find it tedious to convert the formula to value after doing VLOOKUP.
Is there a better way to do this? I'm open to solutions using Python.
Here's another visualization to show what I want to do


Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See Format Text as a Table for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

If I understand correctly, I would have 3 tabs 1) a Beginning of Month Master List (your original master list), 2) the July (current month) list and 3) an End of Month Master List which would be a bunch of look up/filters formulas OR scripting combining 1 and 2. For August your End of Month becomes your new Beginning of month (copy/paste values or link to july EOM spreadsheet).
